# SQL Server IQID key for insert

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table in our system:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VCMANAGER](
    [IQID] [char](32) NOT NULL,
    [ACCOUNT] [char](32) NULL,
    [FUND] [char](32) NULL,
    [GROUPINVEST] [char](32) NULL,
    [PORTFOLIO] [char](32) NULL,
    [PROJECT] [char](32) NULL,
    [PRJGUARANTEE] [char](32) NULL,
    [KIND] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [MANAGERROLE] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [INFORMATIONS] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
    [STARTDATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [ENDDATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [PARTNER] [char](32) NULL,
    [DISPLAYINDEX] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_VCMANAGER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IQID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Question: how do I create an `ID` to insert values into this table? (what goes where the ??? are?)

```
insert into VCMANAGER(IQID, ACCOUNT, KIND, PARTNER)     
   select 
      ???, account, 'COLEAD', 'F817090E50AD41F4BF2F7AA55262D6B7' 
   from 
      #rainer 
   where  
      colead is null
```

Thanks for your answer!

Cheers,
Markus

Comment: You should check into `INT IDENTITY` for your `ID` column. In that case, SQL Server will automagically and without any hassle and effort on your end handle the creation of `ID` values.....